# Clarification on matters relating the the differential operator in Sturm Liouville

Tags: partial-differential-equations

My set of two notes, one of which might contain a printing error.

In Sturm-Liouville problem, is the differential operator expressed as 
$$L(y) = \frac{d}{\text{dx}}\text{((P(x) }\frac{d}{\text{dx}}\text{)+q(x)}$$

or

$$L(y)=\frac{-d}{\text{dx}}\text{[P(x)}\frac{\text{dy}}{\text{dx}}\text{]+q(x)y(x)}$$

Which is the correct expresson?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe they both have small typo's, for instance the left hand side of the first definition has a $y$, but the right hand side does not. I do not see why the second definition has a minus sign, but redefining the assumptions on $P(x),q(x)$, it should be okay, though it seems unnecessary. I would put them as follows:

$$L=\frac{d}{dx}(P(x)\frac{d}{dx})+q(x),$$ and
$$L(y)=\frac{d}{dx}(P(x)\frac{dy}{dx})+q(x)y.$$